# Case sensitivity in Windows batch script when searching for plugin name

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a Windows batch script that takes user input and looks for that plugin on the user's local machine. It's been working well, until I found out that the search for the plugin isn't case sensitive.

So, if I have a plugin called com.test123, but I type Com.test123 as the plugin name, the batch file continues with no issues. This prevents a build call in the batch script from working. Is it possible to do a case sensitive search for the plugin name?

This is the code I'm currently using (case insensitive):

```
:start
echo.
echo ***********************************************************
echo.
set tmpDate=
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined tmpDate set tmpDate=%%x
set YYYYMMDD=%tmpDate:~0,4%%tmpDate:~4,2%%tmpDate:~6,2%

set DITA_DIR= %cd%\..\..\dita-ot-3.7\
set DitaSource= %cd%\..

:plugin
SET /p plugin=Enter a plugin: 
IF EXIST %DitaSource%\%plugin% (
    goto format
    ) else (
    echo Couldn't find the specified plugin.
    echo.
    goto plugin
    )

:format
SET /p format=Enter an output format (or 'r' to reset the plugin identifier): 
if %format%==pdf-qnx goto buildPDF
if %format%==r goto start
echo You must provide one of the following output formats: pdf-qnx, xhtml, eclipsehelp, webhelp-responsive
echo.

:tryagain
echo Enter the plugin identifier: %plugin%
SET /p format=Enter the output format (or 'r' to reset the plugin identifier): 
if %format%==pdf-qnx goto buildPDF
if %format%==r goto start
echo You must provide one of the following output formats: pdf-qnx, xhtml, eclipsehelp, webhelp-responsive
echo.
goto tryagain

:buildPDF
@copy %DitaSource%\buildfiles-3.7\vars.ditamap %DitaSource%\%plugin%>NUL
:: Delete the existing book.pdf file, if possible
if EXIST %DitaSource%\%plugin%\%format%\book.pdf del %DitaSource%\%plugin%\%format%\book.pdf
:: Couldn't delete the book.pdf file, likely because the file is open. Redirect to the BUILD FAILED message and try again.
if EXIST %DitaSource%\%plugin%\%format%\book.pdf goto fail
call %DITA_DIR%bin\dita -i %DitaSource%\%plugin%\book.ditamap -f %format% -o %DitaSource%\%plugin%\%format%\ --propertyfile=%DitaSource%\buildfiles-3.7\%format%.properties
del %DitaSource%\%plugin%\vars.ditamap
if EXIST %DitaSource%\%plugin%\%format%\book.pdf (
echo.
echo BUILD SUCCESSFUL
) else (
:fail
echo.
echo BUILD FAILED
)
goto start
```

Edit: Here is a complete example of what I'm trying to accomplish. The entered plugin is used in the 'dita' command (using DITA OpenToolkit) to build various output formats (in this example, PDF). When the script executes the 'dita' command, the command can't find the plugin because of case sensitivity. Although this issue may be caused by the dita process, I was hoping there's a way to warn users in the batch script.

Comment: You are correct, `If Exist` is not case sensitive! There is nothing you have submitted which shows us exactly what you are doing, and reproduces an answerable issue. Please [Edit] your question, to include more of your code, (we need a [mcve]).

Comment: Windows doesn't have case sensitivity for file names. It considers `Com.test.123` and `com.test.123` to be the same filename (you can test this yourself by creating two files and trying to give it those names; you'll get a "would you like to rename the file" error for the second one). If your processing script is case-sensitive, rewrite the processing script. There's probably just a `/I` somewhere that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If Exist is not case sensitive. You can add a subroutine to compare your plugin name with the name of the file. See the code below. I have used only a check for filename, but if necessary you can check for case sensitive directory in a similar way.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal
if Not Exist "SearchFile.txt" echo . > "SearchFile.txt"
set "SearchFile1=SearchFile.txt"
set "SearchFile2=searchfile.tXt"

set "CaseEqual="
IF EXIST "%SearchFile1%" (
   echo File is found
   CALL :CheckCase "%SearchFile1%"
)
IF DEFINED CaseEqual If "%CaseEqual%" == "True" (echo case sensitive match) ELSE (echo case does not match!)

set "CaseEqual="
IF EXIST "%SearchFile2%" (
   echo File is found
   CALL :CheckCase "%SearchFile2%"
)
IF DEFINED CaseEqual If "%CaseEqual%" == "True" (echo case sensitive match) ELSE (echo case does not match!)

endlocal
exit /b

:CheckCase
FOR %%A IN ("%~1") DO IF "%~1" == "%%~nxA" (SET "CaseEqual=True") ELSE (SET "CaseEqual=False")
exit /b
```